# Duplicate or Clone the Bank Transfer Payment Module | How?

Tags: opencart

Duplicate or Clone the Bank Transfer Payment Module | How?

Currently using OpenCart 1.5.5.1.

My inquiry is like so...

How to duplicate the Banks Transfer Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy all files related to this module and rename (controller, template etc.)
2. Change class name ex. `ControllerPaymentBankTransfer` > `ControllerMyCustomBankTransfer`
3. change all references to `bank_transfer` with your custom files

Once cloned, you can edit the code to accommodate your needs

Comment: I want to duplicate the bank transfer module because I want to name it to another Payment Name, but same functionality. Lets say, I 'll call it... Bank Deposit Payment.

Comment: though this post had been close, I got the answer that fulfilled my goal. Thanks!